# On error message

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to put an on error message to below code (so if there is a runtime error, i want the msgbox to appear and the code to stop running when user clicks on the error message. I gave it a shot below but having some issue where the code doesn’t run as i like it to. Wondering if anyone could help me.

```
Dim HL As Hyperlink
       For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
 On Error GoTo ErrorMsgBox
         HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address
         HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileDateTime(HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        Exit Sub
ErrorMsgBox:
           MsgBox ("Error")
           Resume Next
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error handling needs to go *outside* of the loop. Also, since you want the code to *stop running*, you should not use `Resume Next` statement.  Also, you have an `Exit Sub` *inside* your `For...Next` loop, which maybe you are confused, but this means your "loop" will only operate *once*, which is almost certainly not what you desire.

Revised:

```
Dim HL As Hyperlink
   For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
   On Error GoTo ErrorMsgBox
       HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address
       HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileDateTime(HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value)
   Next

'# Put the exit statement *before* your error handler, and *outside* of the loop
   Exit Sub 

'# Error handler will inform user and end sub.
ErrorMsgBox:
   MsgBox ("Error")
   Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: weird indenting but definitely +1

Comment: @mehow I just copied OP's indenting :) I've fixed it now, though!

Comment: Ah ok thanks for your input. It works!! One another issue maybe you can shed some light. It’s very weird but here's the issue:  Before running the code i need to save the file first or else it gives me the path not found error. Don’t know why this happens but can you provide some input if possible?

Comment: Why don't you *accept* this answer (since it has solved the immediate problem) and ask a new question for help with this new problem you're having.

Comment: I would guess something in your code is trying to reference a *path* property (perhaps a hyperlink to a document location, or another file, etc.) and if the file(s) are not saved, they may not have a *path* which can be referenced.  but that's all I can say for now... If you do post a new question, start there with your troubleshooting and I'm sure you will get some more help. Cheers!